# Angular routeProvider only recognizes #/foo, not #!/foo. Likes hash. Hates hash bang

Tags: angularjs

My app works fine with routes such as:

```
when('/people/new', { templateUrl: 'partials/person-detail.html', controller: 'PersonDetailCtrl' }).
when('/people/:id', { templateUrl: 'partials/person-detail.html', controller: 'PersonDetailCtrl' })
```

I can link to these as href="#/people/23" but href="#!/people/23" isn't recognized and my .otherwise() default route is followed.

What am I missing? Every doc and online reference I can find says the path should begin with #!.

Comment: Do you try to add a $location.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')?

Comment: hashPrefix is it. Thanks. If you put it in an answer I will credit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `$location.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')`